# How secure are OfficeJS Add-ins?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I wrote an Excel Add-in using VSTO in C#, and it's compiled into a DLL file which is relatively secure considering many users won't know how to get the decompiled code. I want this to work on Excel for Mac, but that doesn't support VSTO.

Microsoft has been touting OfficeJS as a solution to cross-platform add-ins. However, JavaScript files can easily be viewed, so how is the integrity of the code preserved? If I try to license this add-in, couldn't the user access the JS file, open it, delete the licensing requirement, use the software for free, and distribute it themselves?

Comment: Your question applies to any web application, so there's really no need to tag it office-js or mention that you're making an Office add-in. I got a really good answer from [Bing Chat](https://www.microsoft.com/edge/features/bing-chat?form=MT00D8) when I asked "How to protect JavaScript intellectual property?"